# I can not change the error message jquery validation plagin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

I want to change the error message, and that it does not work

```
  $('form').validate();
  messages: {
    "form[name]": "test",
  }
});
```

how fix?

I think the problem was not in the script only, but also in html.vot just can not understand what I'm doing wrong, it is necessary that the form "name" would pass validation.

this my html

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <%= f.label "Название" %>

        <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", required: :require  %>
      </div>
```

Comment: what is the name of the generated input element?

Comment: you have syntax error in your script... `$('form').validate({
    messages: {
        "form[name]": {
            required: "test"
        }
    }
});`

Comment: <input id="event_name" class="form-control" type="text" required="required" name="event[name]">

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in the script, also the name used is wrong so

```
$('form').validate({
    messages: {
        "event[name]": {
            required: "test"
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2hzd6rh8/1/)

Comment: if I need to add one more line of a "email" like this will look like?

Comment: @weare138 another field or same

Answer (score 0):

Messages is a parameter of validate therefore your syntax is wrong.

Try:

```
  $('form').validate({
    messages: {
      "form[name]": "test"
    }
  });
```

Further reading: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/